# vb.net searching for a search within a string

Tags: vb.net

```
lot_no = "lot123"

s.indexof("lot123") does not return zero
```

whereas

```
s.indexof(lot_no) returns zero
```

has anyone seen a problem like this?

what does s contain?

```
    For Each s As String In split1
```

Comment: sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639443/vb-net-weird-behavior-with-getting-position-of-string  ,more ++'s for good questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K, looked add the code in your other thread.
When I execute the following code I get a result, what am I doing wrong?

```
Public lot__no As String = "<Lot no>928374</Lot no>"
Sub DoSomething()
    Dim temp_string As String = "<beginning of record>ETCETCETC" 
   Dim myDelims As String() = New String() {"<beginning of record>"}
    Dim Split() As String = temp_string.Split(myDelims, StringSplitOptions.None)

    For Each s As String In Split
        If InStr(s, lot__no) <> 0 Then
            Debug.WriteLine("found" + s)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: the thing is, my friend, i am certain your code is fine, and i am certain my code is fine, but there must be a low-level problem PLEASE HELP

Comment: Right, this seems a weird problem indeed. Have you tried creating a new application and tried this code again?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking but this code returns -1 / -1

```
Dim lotnr As String = "lot123"
For Each s As String In "123asd"
    Debug.WriteLine(s.IndexOf("lot123"))
    Debug.WriteLine(s.IndexOf(lotnr))
Next
```

Use IndexOf this way:

```
Dim lotnr As String = "lot123"
For Each s As String In "123asd"
    Debug.WriteLine("lot123".IndexOf(s))
    Debug.WriteLine(lotnr.IndexOf(s))
Next
```

This results in:
3
3
4
4
5
5
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1

Comment: interesting, can you please give me an example what the values of s in this case?